# take ownwership of system folder of external HDD

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, chkdsk, ownership

I would like to access 'system volume information' folder of my external HDD (WD my book 2TB) to view results of chkdsk process.
(I want to know the list of damaged file names)
When I try to open the folder, the access is denied.

Right-click the folder -> properties shows that
the user 'SYSTEM' has full permissions and there is no other user.

The OS is Windows 7 64bit and I have admin privilege and am the only user of this desktop computer.

Comment: You would need to Add your user to the permissions, then make it the owner.

Comment: @Moab That doesn't work. I can't do that. That's the reason I posted this question.

Answer (score -1):

i find answer of your question in microsoft site : [full access to ALL files and folders in Win 7](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/i-want-full-access-to-all-my-files-and-folders-in/1567bf63-b1f5-40a5-be3f-150dce4c5aed?auth=1) 
 i say one part that close to your question: 
 **How to Take Ownership in Windows 7**

1. Locate the file or folder on which you want to take ownership in windows explorer
2. Right click on file or folder and select “Properties” from Context Menu
3. Click on Security tab
4. Click on “Advance”
5. Now click on Owner tab in Advance Security Settings for User windows
6. Click on Edit Button and select user from given Change Owner to list if user or group is not in given list then click on other users or groups. Enter name of user/group and click ok.
7. Now select User/group and click apply and ok. (Check “Replace owner on sub containers and objects” if you have files and folder within selected folder)
8. Click ok when Windows Security Prompt is displayed
9. Now Owner name must have changed.
10. Now click Ok to exist from Properties windows

Once you have taken the ownership of file or folder next part comes is Granting Permissions to that file/folder or object.

**How to Grant Permissions in Windows 7**

1. Locate the file or folder on which you want to take ownership in windows explorer
2. Right click on file or folder and select “Properties” from Context Menu
3. Click on Edit button in Properties windows Click ok to confirm UAC elevation request.
4. Select user/group from permission windows or click add to add other user or group.
5. Now under Permission section check the rights which you want to grant i.e check “Full Control” under the “Allow” column to assign full access rights control permissions to Administrators group.
6. Click Ok for changes to take effect and click ok final ok to exit from Properties window.

Now you can access files of folder in windows 7 with full permissions and take full control.

**in finally when you want use this chkdsk i found another way for your work: [list-and-remove-corrupted-files-with-powershell](http://www.isolation.se/list-and-remove-corrupted-files-reported-by-data-deduplication-with-powershell/)**

Comment: This method does not work for me.
In addition, what I want is NOT remove corrupted files, but get the LIST of corrupted files.